# Hadoop ApplicationMaster compute nodes determination

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

ApplicationMaster component in Hadoop YARN architecture, requests for compute resources on cluster nodes. As per Hadoop's philosophy of bringing computation closer to the data, ApplicationMaster should be asking for compute resources on the same nodes that have the data for the application task. My query is how does ApplicationMaster determine the nodes that have the data for the task. Does it communicate with the NameNode for the this information.

Comment: There is no other way. Namenode is the central metadata repository in Hadoop

Comment: Thanks. I could not find this information in articles or documentation.